# JApplet will start but not initialize

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, japplet

First time poster and obvious n00b java student. I have been working on this forever, scouring the internet for the last two days and anything I try yields no results. This was originally a program using JFrame and I need to convert it to an Applet. The code compiles fine with no errors and starts the applet but that's it. I get a gray window and says "Applet Started". It is supposed to display graphics that switch a smile to a frown and back again on a timer. I'm not looking for anyone to finish my homework (as I trust you wouldn't) I just need some guidance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
public class GAPanel extends JApplet {

public void init() {

    System.out.println("In init");
    this.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

}

protected class GAPane extends JPanel implements ActionListener {


public final int FACE_FROWN = 1;
public final int FACE_SMILE = 2;    
private int face = FACE_SMILE;
private Timer timer = null;
{
    timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    timer.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics paint) {

    super.paintComponents(paint);
    System.out.println("In paint");
    this.setBackground(java.awt.Color.blue);
    Graphics2D betterpaint = (Graphics2D) paint;
    betterpaint.drawOval(300, 300, 100, 100);

    paint.setColor(Color.yellow);
    betterpaint.fillOval(300, 300, 100, 100);

    paint.setColor(Color.black);
    betterpaint.drawOval(325, 325, 10, 10);

    paint.setColor(Color.white);
    betterpaint.fillOval(325, 325, 10, 10);
    paint.setColor(Color.black);
    betterpaint.drawOval(365, 325, 10, 10);
    paint.setColor(Color.white);
    betterpaint.fillOval(365, 325, 10, 10);
    paint.setColor(Color.black);
    betterpaint.fillOval(329, 329, 3, 3);
    betterpaint.fillOval(368, 329, 3, 3);
    paint.setColor(Color.black);


    switch (face){
        case FACE_FROWN:
         betterpaint.drawArc(325, 350, 50, 45, 0, 180);
            break;
        case FACE_SMILE:
         betterpaint.drawArc(325, 325, 50, 50, 200, 140);
            break;
    }

}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    face = face == FACE_FROWN ? FACE_SMILE : FACE_FROWN;

    this.repaint();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"This was originally a program using JFrame and I need to convert it to an Applet."* I see from the code you mean `JApplet` but ..why?  It is usually better to launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Change `public void paintComponent(Graphics paint) {

    super.paintComponents(paint);` to `public void paintComponent(Graphics paint) {

    super.paintComponent(paint);` (note use of plural/singular forms)!

Answer (score 1):

Your JApplet's `init()` overrride is kind of sparse:

```
public void init() {
    System.out.println("In init");
    this.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
}
```

In fact you don't do anything really useful in it such as adding a GUI to your JApplet's contentPane, so it makes sense that nothing will show. I suggest that you do this, that you create your JPanel and add it to the applet in the `init()` method. If you haven't gone through the applet tutorials you will want to do that now as this is all explained well there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. this.add(new GAPane()); in my init method fixed it. The setLayout(new BorderLayout()); shouldn't haven't been in there at all. Finals week... everything has been fuzzy. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Although JFrames and JApplet's are different utilities, they share a lot of basic functions you are required to use to actually initialize them. From what I can see, you've created a JPanel that holds your smiley face code, but you never actually designated it to be the content pane for your applet. This is probably why you are seeing a gray screen: your applet was created, but not filled with any content.

```
setContentPane(new GAPane());
```

I think that should do the trick. Though there are a lot of other things I think you may run into with this code if you just switched it to JFrame without understanding JApplets. Check out this Oracle page, it has a nice documentation and a few examples too:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html